# JQuery Mobile loses style when runat="server" is added to the control

Tags: asp.net, css, jquery-mobile, runatserver

I'm trying to implement JQuery Mobile checkbox, but it has to be accessible form the server side.

This is the usual JQM ckeckbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chckTOC" id="chckTOCs" class="custom" />
<label for="chckTOCs">Include Table of Content</label>
```

[image: Styled checkbox without runat="server"]

When I add runat="server" property to the checkbox it losses it's style.

[image: And a the result with runat="server"]

I've tried using `<asp:Checkbox>`  but still doesn't have the expected JQM style.

Any ideas how to make the control server available and still to be styled?

**SOLVED see the answer**

Comment: Are you applying any css class at runtime using javascript??

Comment: Nope, I don't think so.

Comment: Any css is dependent on id or name of control?

Comment: What does ASP.net render the checkbox in the output html source code for the page?  I'm thinking you can probably easily tell what's wrong if you see the actual HTML that's output.  Also, regarding CSS, usually the ASP.NET controls have a "CssClass" attribute, rather than the usual "class" attribute, but not sure if that will make any difference.

Comment: `<asp:CheckBox ID="chckTOC" runat="server" />` is rendered into
`<input id="cpmain_chckTOC" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cpmain$chckTOC" checked="checked">`

Comment: YESS :) I found the reason -> the checkbox id when rendered is changed from `chckTOC` to `cpmain_chckTOC`, so if I make the `<label for='cpmain_chckTOC' />` is working : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the guys in the comments section I found the reason. When rendered the checkbox id is changed from `chckTOC` to `cpmain_chckTOC` and the label tag it was not valid. I've changed the label tag to `<label for='cpmain_chckTOC' />` and now I've got a brand new styled checkbox as expected.

I've also managed to avoid this hardcode id -> `<label for='cpmain_chckTOC' />`, because it would be a problem for example, if you have your checkbox inside an APS repeater - then each checkbox id will be different something like **"cpmain_repeaterid_chckTOC_1"** and then **"cpmain_repeaterid_chckTOC_2"** and so on. And in this situation hardcoded id won't help you.

Instead I've managed to do it using only ASP.NET controls:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chckSelectAll" CssClass="custom" />
<asp:label id="lblForChckAll" AssociatedControlID="chckSelectAll" runat="server" />
```

And now the result is as expected:

[image]

Comment: I always add a class to use as a jQuery selector, exactly to avoid this kind of behavior.

Comment: Using class is one wait to go, but not in this situation, because `<label for='cpmain_chckTOC' />` is associated with an ID as I know. See my edit -> I've managed to do it in a better way using simply ASP.NET controls.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that. I just try to avoid the use of IDs as selectors, because you can ended up having to change it all again if you use MasterPages. It's a pain.